# When i create New android project using eclipse it create two xml layout

Tags: android, eclipse

My old eclipse version worked perfectly but after updating eclipse, when I create a new Android project, it creates two XML layouts. 1st is activity_main.xml and second is fragment.xml. So when i add some item in activity_main.xml it wont display anything.

So how to use fragment layout?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 2):

This is the new Project Structure for Android by developers.

If you want to view any UI widgets put them inside **fragment.xml** file.

And any java code should put inside **PlacementHolder** class that is inner class of Main.java.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned that's just the recent new project style from Android Team. But I guess you were also looking for an introduction into Fragments when you asked:

```
 So how to use fragment layout?
```

### Basically:

Android team has completely covered Fragments in their documentation. Start from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and then refer [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html). Then download [this official source code](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/FragmentBasics.zip) and examine it closely.

### Now I'm gonna share a personal experience:

I suggest you first study [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html) on fragments from Vogella's website.

Why? Because the Android documentation is slow and rather boring there fore hard to understand, whereas the Vogella version is to-the-point and sharp.

You can then go back and study Android documentation.

Answer (score -1):

at least read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html it will give you an idea how the fragments work. And better switch now to Android Studio, the sooner the better.